# Umbraco SurfaceController - cannot get CurrentPage

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, umbraco

I have a SurfaceController that performs a Get method. When I attempt to access the current page using this.CurrentPage, I get the following error

> Cannot find the Umbraco route definition in the route values, the
>   request must be made in the context of an Umbraco request

Why is my controller not able to see the current page?

{
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
...
    using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;

```
public class BenefitStatementPdfSurfaceController : SurfaceController
{
    private readonly SelfServiceApiHttpClient _apiClient;

    public MySurfaceController(SelfServiceApiHttpClient apiClient)
    {
        _apiClient = apiClient;
    }

    [ActionName("MemberPdf")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> MemberPdfAsync(int memberNumber, int selectedYear)
    {
        var content = await _apiClient
                                .MemberPdfAsync(memberNumber, selectedYear)
                                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (content.HasPdf)
        {
                return this.File(content.Pdf, "application/pdf", $"Statement{selectedYear}_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd}_{DateTime.Now:HHmmss}.pdf");
        }

        var nodeId = this.CurrentPage.Id; ------ERRORS HERE
       ...
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does removing `.ConfigureAwait(false)` change anything?

Comment: No, still the same error

Comment: Hey man, If I'm correct being in a surface controller, you are not in the umbracocontext by default but the Surface Controller provides an Umbraco Helper. I've done something like this recently and what I did was pass the id of the page (it was an ajax call on mine) and then used Umbraco.TypedContent(pageId). That will give you the current page and you can access the current page properties from there. 'Umbraco' in this case is the Umbraco helper. Did that help?

P.S. I think you can also use 'AssignedContentItem' to get the properties of the page, unless it's Nested Content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to work with the current UmbracoContext.

Umbraco has some helper methods you can use.

Can you try the following code:

```
UmbracoHelper helper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
IPublishedContent content = helper.TypedContent(Node.getCurrentNodeId());
```